# Plotting real spherical harmonics with SphericalPlot3D - odd functions overlap themselves, even functions ok

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, special-functions

I want to reproduce plots of **real** spherical harmonics as shown on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_spherical_harmonics#Polar_plots_with_magnitude_as_radius_2).
I used:

```
RealSphericalHarmonicY[l_, m_, \[Theta]_, \[Phi]_] := Which[
  m < 0, \[Sqrt]2 (-1)^m Im[SphericalHarmonicY[l, -m, \[Theta], \[Phi]]],
  m == 0, SphericalHarmonicY[l, m, \[Theta], \[Phi]],
  m > 0, \[Sqrt]2 (-1)^m Re[SphericalHarmonicY[l, m, \[Theta], \[Phi]]]
]
    
Do[
 Print[GraphicsRow[Table[
    SphericalPlot3D[
     Re[SphericalHarmonicY[l, m, \[Theta], \[Phi]]], {\[Theta], 0, \[Pi]}, {\[Phi], 0, 2 \[Pi]},
     MeshStyle -> None, Axes -> False, Boxed -> False,
     ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, \[Theta], \[Phi], r}, 
       ColorData["TemperatureMap"][Sign[RealSphericalHarmonicY[l, m, \[Theta], \[Phi]]]]], 
     ColorFunctionScaling -> False],
    {m, -l, l}], ImageSize -> {900, 100}]],
 {l, 0, 4}]
```

Producing the following output:

[image: plot]

As you can see, all odd functions are folded onto themselves, with the positive and negative phase "lobes" overlapping. If one of the phases would be inverted around the origin, the plots would be accurate. How can these be fixed?

To be sure I did not mess up the definitions, I tried alternative but equivalent definitions for the real spherical harmonics (see e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_harmonics#Real_form)):

```
RealSphericalHarmonicY[l_, m_, \[Theta]_, \[Phi]_] := Which[
  m < 0, I/\[Sqrt]2 (SphericalHarmonicY[l, m, \[Theta], \[Phi]] - (-1)^m SphericalHarmonicY[l, -m, \[Theta], \[Phi]]),
  m == 0, SphericalHarmonicY[l, m, \[Theta], \[Phi]],
  m > 0, 1/\[Sqrt]2 (SphericalHarmonicY[l, -m, \[Theta], \[Phi]] + (-1)^m SphericalHarmonicY[l, m, \[Theta], \[Phi]])
]
```

or

```
RealSphericalHarmonicY[l_, m_, \[Theta]_, \[Phi]_] := Which[
  m < 0, (-1)^m/(I\[Sqrt]2) (SphericalHarmonicY[l, -m, \[Theta], \[Phi]] - SphericalHarmonicY[l, -m, \[Theta], \[Phi]]\[Conjugate]),
  m == 0, SphericalHarmonicY[l, m, \[Theta], \[Phi]],
  m > 0, (-1)^m/\[Sqrt]2 (SphericalHarmonicY[l, m, \[Theta], \[Phi]] + SphericalHarmonicY[l, m, \[Theta], \[Phi]]\[Conjugate])
]
```

They are indeed equivalent, producing the same result.
I am likely missing something obvious. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `Abs` before `Re` in your code (I also changed coloring function appropriately and added `PlotRange -> All`):

```
Do[Print[GraphicsRow[
   Table[SphericalPlot3D[
     Abs@Re[SphericalHarmonicY[l, m, θ, φ]], {θ, 
      0, π}, {φ, 0, 2 π}, MeshStyle -> None, 
     Axes -> False, Boxed -> False, 
     ColorFunction -> 
      Function[{x, y, z, θ, φ, r}, 
       Hue[Arg[Re[
           SphericalHarmonicY[l, m, θ, φ]]]/(2 π)]], 
     ColorFunctionScaling -> False, PlotRange -> All], {m, -l, l}], 
   ImageSize -> {900, 100}]], {l, 0, 4}]
```

---

[image]